# Problem with DirectionsApiRequest and apiRequest.setCallback

Tags: java, android, google-directions-api

Wrote a method for creating and overlaying a route between two points. The problem is that when it's triggered in normal mode (without breakpoints), it causes `NullPointerException` or `IllegalStateException`, but when I run my app in Debug-mode it throws nothing and works correctly.
I'm sorry for my english (i'm from Russia) and I apologize for formulation of the question, I'm still not really familiar with stackoverflow.

Here is my method:

```
    List<com.google.maps.model.LatLng> path;
    DirectionsRoute[] routes;
    DisplayMetrics metricsB = new DisplayMetrics();
    int width = metricsB.widthPixels;
    int heith = metricsB.heightPixels;
    PolylineOptions line = new PolylineOptions();
    LatLngBounds.Builder latLngBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    String dist;

    public void TravelCost(LatLng startGeoPoint, LatLng stopGeoPoint) throws InterruptedException,
ApiException, IOException {

        GeoApiContext geoApiContext = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
                .apiKey(maps_api_key)
                .build();

        DirectionsApiRequest apiRequest = DirectionsApi.newRequest(geoApiContext);

        apiRequest.origin(new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(startGeoPoint.latitude, startGeoPoint.longitude));
        apiRequest.destination(new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(stopGeoPoint.latitude, stopGeoPoint.longitude));
        apiRequest.mode(TravelMode.DRIVING); //set travelling mode

        apiRequest.setCallback(new com.google.maps.PendingResult.Callback<DirectionsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DirectionsResult result) {
                routes = result.routes;
                path = routes[0].overviewPolyline.decodePath();
                dist = routes[0].legs[0].distance.humanReadable;
                for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
                    line.add(new com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(path.get(i).lat, path.get(i).lng));
                    latLngBuilder.include(new com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(path.get(i).lat, path.get(i).lng));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        line.width(16f).color(R.color.purple_500);
        map.addPolyline(line);
        LatLngBounds latLngBounds = latLngBuilder.build();
        CameraUpdate track = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, 1080, 1920, 25);
        map.moveCamera(track);
    }
```

Here are errors from log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.plukash.travelcost, PID: 19561
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no included points
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Unknown Source:29)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds$Builder.build(Unknown Source:21)
        at com.plukash.travelcost.MapsActivity.TravelCost(MapsActivity.java:305)
        at com.plukash.travelcost.MapsActivity.onMapSearch(MapsActivity.java:142)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

This is XML-layout file.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/LocSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:hint="Куда поедем?"
                android:inputType="text"
                tools:ignore="Autofill,HardcodedText" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/search_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:onClick="onMapSearch"  <------- OnClick Method
                android:text="Search"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MapsActivity"
            tools:ignore="FragmentTagUsage" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/go_px"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is a On-click method for Search-button that calls for "TravelCost" method.

```
public void onMapSearch(View view) throws InterruptedException, ApiException, IOException {
        boolean bool = TrafficJam();
        try {
            Button search = findViewById(R.id.search_button);

            String location = locationSearch.getText().toString();
            List<Address> addressList;

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast toast = new Toast(this);
                toast.setText("Введите корректный адрес!");
                toast.show();
                return;
            }
            if (addressList != null) {
                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                //Убирать ли текст в поисковом поле?
                //locationSearch.setText("");
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(search.getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            } else {
                Toast toast = new Toast(this);
                toast.setText("Введите адрес!");
                toast.show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast toast = new Toast(this);
            toast.setText("Введите корректный адрес!");
            toast.show();
            return;
        }
        if (checker == 1) {
            startpoint = latLng;
            checker += 1;
            locationSearch.setText("");
            locationSearch.setHint("Куда поедем?");
        } else if (checker == 2) {
            LatLng endpoint = latLng;
            locationSearch.setText("Откуда поедем?");
            checker = 1;
            TravelCost(startpoint, endpoint); <-------------- Method call
        }
    }
```

**UPD**

Need to return values from other Thread.

```
DirectionsRoute[] routes;
    public void TravelCost(LatLng startGeoPoint, LatLng stopGeoPoint) {
        GeoApiContext geoApiContext = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
                .apiKey("AIzaSyA9qY28oZ-4TTdDt1jgxdCKLYh9T8Kh0Ss")
                .build();

        DirectionsApiRequest apiRequest = DirectionsApi.newRequest(geoApiContext);
        apiRequest.origin(new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(startGeoPoint.latitude, startGeoPoint.longitude));
        apiRequest.destination(new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(stopGeoPoint.latitude, stopGeoPoint.longitude));
        apiRequest.mode(TravelMode.DRIVING);
        apiRequest.language("Russian");//set travelling mode


        AppExecutors.getInstance().networkIO().execute(() -> {
            apiRequest.setCallback(new com.google.maps.PendingResult.Callback<DirectionsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DirectionsResult result) {
                    routes = result.routes;
<---- **routes here contains values**   
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        });
<---- **Here routes is nullarray.**
        List<com.google.maps.model.LatLng> path = routes[0].overviewPolyline.decodePath();   
        dist = routes[0].legs[0].distance.humanReadable;
        for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
            line.add(new com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(path.get(i).lat, path.get(i).lng));
            latLngBuilder.include(new com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng(path.get(i).lat, path.get(i).lng));
        }

        line.width(16f).color(R.color.purple_500);
        map.addPolyline(line);
        LatLngBounds latLngBounds = latLngBuilder.build();
        CameraUpdate track = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, 1080, 1920, 25);
        map.moveCamera(track);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Looks like your problem is with the `android:onClick` are you sure that you typed the method currently in the xml? It would be helpful if you could share your XML

Comment: Updated question with XML and OnClick method. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Is `onMapSearch` in the layout of the activity? basically, what that error is saying is that it's not finding the `onMapSearch` not sure why, are you running proguard when you build the app?  proguard may be changing the name of the method

Comment: It's also considered to be bad practice to use `android:onClick` it's better to use a click listener, I will post an answer to help you out

Comment: @TiagoOliveira Thanks for the correction) I'm just a Junior-dev, so i don't know a lot of dev tricks, i'm still learning.

Comment: It's okay! We have all been there :)

Comment: You need to move the code to `onResult`  this line `... routes[0].overview...` runs before  `routes = result.routes`

Comment: So any access to the array should be done when the `onResult` is called, otherwise, it will cause an NPE, the code runs in the background, but the code outside the `Executor` keeps running, you are trying to access an array before the process finishes, I hope I'm explaining this right

Comment: @TiagoOliveira But i can't access Maps.UI from callback method and i can't perform `map.addPolyline(line);` from there

Comment: I believe the IDE is asking you to convert `map`  to a final array am I right? I haven't used java for a long time, I mainly use Kotlin now, but I remember having similar problems with java

Comment: @TiagoOliveira the IDE is asking me about all included variables (`LatLngBounds`, `routes`) but not about the map. Now my methods just create two markers on the map, but not the route-line between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be with the `android:onClick` the system is not finding the method and it's throwing an error because of it.

My hypothesis is that this is happening because you are running the app with proguard enabled, proguard may be changing the method name, and this will cause this exception.

I would advise using a click listener since it's considered to be bad practice to use the `android:onClick`

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.search_button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onMapSearch(v);
            }
        });

        // implementation of an onclick listener using a lambda instead
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> onMapSearch(v));
    }
```

Also, you may consider deleting the view parameter in `onMapSearch` since it's not used anymore

#### EDIT

To fix the `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` you need to run the network call outside of the main thread, note that it's not advisable to use AsyncTask since it's has been deprecated for a long time now.

Worker example

```
public class AppExecutors {

    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
    private static AppExecutors sInstance;
    private static Executor processor;
    private final Executor diskIO;
    private final Executor networkIO;
    private final Executor mainThread;

    private AppExecutors(Executor diskIO, Executor networkIO, Executor mainThread){
        this.diskIO = diskIO;
        this.networkIO = networkIO;
        this.mainThread = mainThread;
    }

    public static AppExecutors getInstance(){
        if(sInstance == null){
            synchronized (LOCK){
                sInstance = new AppExecutors(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
                        Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3),
                        new MainThreadExecutor());
            }
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    public Executor diskIO() {
        return diskIO;
    }

    public Executor networkIO() {
        return networkIO;
    }

    public Executor getMainThread() {
        return mainThread;
    }

    private static class MainThreadExecutor implements Executor {
        private final Handler mainThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        @Override
        public void execute(@NotNull Runnable command) {
            mainThreadHandler.post(command);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
AppExecutors.getInstance().networkIO().execute(() -> {
    // Network call goes here       
});
```

Comment: Thanks for good advice. I've replaced OnClick with setOnCliickListener, but it had no effect. Now it throws 
`android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Comment: I believe it will be solved with using of AsyncTask, probably.

Comment: AsyncTask is deprecated and should not be used, you can use an executor for example, I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I've spent about an hour trying to find a solution, and you've just done it in 20 minutes. Real God!)

Comment: There is still a problem that throws `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array` from `.execute()`. How can I get values from another thread?

Comment: I will add my code as an edit to the question.